# Scikit learn - output average probability of right choice

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

So I'm messing around with a three outcome dataframe with Scikit-Learn. I'm more interested in predicting accurate probability rather than predicting the right outcome. Thus I use predict_proba rather than predict, and I can then output all the probabilities for each test instance being a, b or c, which is smooth!

Is there any way to do a "probability score" the same way the accuracy_score(y_predictions, y_test) works? So that I get the average probability it has attributed each correct outcome?

I can do this manually by copying it over to Excel or similar but it takes a lot of time..

Thanks!

EDIT - this is what predict_proba outputs:

```
       A    B    C
1    [ 0.6  0.3  0.1]      
2    [ 0.4  0.1  0.5]
3    [ 0.4  0.3  0.3]
4    [ 0.3  0.1  0.6]
...
```

Now, assuming the outcomes of instance 1 and 2 is A, the outcome for instance 3 is C, and the outcome of instance 4 is B, that would give my model an "average probability of correct outcome" of (0.6 + 0.4 + 0.3 + 0.1) / number of instances (in this case 4) which is 0,35 or 35 %.

I have the accurate results stored in y_test (of course) so I want to quickly be able to get this average probability of correct outcome for around the ~500 instances in my test set.

Comment: Can you add an example of the output you get from `predict_proba`, and an example of what you would expect from the "probability score"?

Comment: Done! Hope it's clear enough =)

Comment: I do not know why you want to do this? But have you tried sklearn.metrics.log_loss. It penalizes the wrong overconfident instances.

Comment: Because the actual probabilities for A and C are quite a lot higher than for B and the whole purpose of my model is to predict probability most correctly, rather than actual outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have integer encoded labels in `y_test`:

```
import numpy as np
probas = np.array([[0.6, 0.3, 0.1], [0.4, 0.1, 0.5], [0.4, 0.3, 0.3], [0.3, 0.1, 0.6]])
y_test = np.array([[0], [0], [2], [1]])
print(y_test)

[[0]
 [0]
 [2]
 [1]]
```

To get the desired result, you can use your true labels to choose the value from each row of `probas` you are interested in, and then take the mean.

```
y_probas = np.choose(y_test.T, probas.T)
print(y_probas)

[[ 0.6  0.4  0.3  0.1]]

avg_proba = np.mean(y_probas)
print(avg_proba)

0.35
```

However, consider using [Log Loss](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html), which is a more standard loss metric for predicted probability:

```
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
log_loss(y_test, probas)

1.2334185632400319
```

Comment: Very nice! And exactly what I wanted! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom python function to do this.

```
import pandas as pd

prob = pd.DataFrame([[ 0.6 ,0.3,0.1],[ 0.4 ,0.1,0.5],[ 0.4 ,0.3,0.3],[ 0.3 
                      ,0.1,0.6]],columns=['A','B','C'])

true = pd.Series(["A","A","C","B"])

def avg_prob(true,prob):
    sum = 0
    for i,p in enumerate(true):
        sum += prob.loc[i,p]
    return sum/len(true)

avg_prob(true,prob)
```

Also look into probability calibration (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html) for better-calibrated probabilities of your classes